# Dynamic SQL to Load azure copy data activity

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to create a dynamic query in copy data activity to extract data based on a timestamp from a table. The lookup also gets the right value

I have tried

1. select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date >
   @{formatDateTime(activity('Lookup_Get Last changed
   date').output.firstRow.lastRecordTimeStamp,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')}
2. select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date >
   @{activity('Lookup_Get Last changed
   date').output.firstRow.lastRecordTimeStamp}
3. select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date >
   @activity('Lookup_Get Last changed
   date').output.firstRow.lastRecordTimeStamp

and other options but it always gives an ERROR 2200 which is a syntax error.

Can someone suggest what is the approach?

if i try this(It works)
select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date >'2019-11-27 16:17:00.000'

Comment: select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date > '@{activity('Lookup_Get Last changed date').output.firstRow.lastRecordTimeStamp}

'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the syntax error coming from SQL or from ADF?

Assuming it is SQL, when building the statement dynamically, you still need 's (quotes) around the where clause value:

```
select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date > **'**@{formatDateTime(activity('Lookup_Get Last changed date').output.firstRow.lastRecordTimeStamp,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')}**'**
```

If it is ADF, try building the value in a concat expression:

```
@concat('select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date > ''', activity('Lookup_Get Last changed date').output.firstRow.lastRecordTimeStamp, '''')
```

In either case, you need quotes around the value.

Answer (score 0):

select * from [dbo].t_tablename where last_changed_date > '@{activity('Lookup_Get Last changed date').output.firstRow.lastRecordTimeStamp}'

The above  code is  working now...as it is a datetime we have to include the activity in between ' '